# NoClassDefFoundException while running TestDFSIO on Hadoop 3.1.4

Tags: java, hadoop

I am running a standard Hadoop IO test program called TestDFSIO using the following command:

> sudo -u hdfs hadoop jar
>   /usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-tests.jar
>   TestDFSIO -write -nrFiles 10 -fileSize 1GB

It's expected to write 10 files 1 GB each on HDFS and report the performance.

Right after the test is run, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: junit/framework/TestCase
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.hadoop.test.MapredTestDriver.<init>(MapredTestDriver.java:109)
    at org.apache.hadoop.test.MapredTestDriver.<init>(MapredTestDriver.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.test.MapredTestDriver.main(MapredTestDriver.java:147)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:318)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:232)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: junit.framework.TestCase
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 21 more
```

The test actually proceeds after throwing the error and eventually shows some results, but I am not sure how reliable they are provided that the test apparently doesn't function the way it's supposed to.

I found [this error to be reported on the Cloudera website](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/TestDFSIO-java-lang-NoClassDefFoundError-HDP-3-1/td-p/285142), but no answer given. Will appreciate any ideas on why this error appears and how to get rid of it.

My system:

CentOS 7

openjdk version "1.8.0_252"

Hadoop 3.1.4 installed via Ambari 2.7.4 from Cloudera binaries

Comment: Hi, have you seen https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-4644 and workarounds suggested there?

Comment: I didn't know about the links - thanks for sharing! I tried one suggested workaround and it worked.